# How can I obtain Etag of a file in a storage account using Python SDK for Azure?

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-account

I want to get the etag associated with a file which is uploaded in my storage account in my python code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the code below:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService

block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name='xx', account_key='xx')

myetag = block_blob_service.get_blob_properties("your_container","the_blob_name").properties.etag

print(myetag)
```

Test result:

[image]

Comment: Following error is encountered:

 handlers could be found for logger "azure.storage.common.storageclient"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "azure_example.py", line 7, in <module>
    myetag = block_blob_service.get_blob_properties("sample","sample1.txt").properties.etag
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/baseblobservice.py", line 1583, in get_blob_properties
    return self._perform_request(request, _parse_blob, [blob_name, snapshot])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/storage/common/storageclient.py", line 430, in _perform_request

Comment: raise ex
azure.common.AzureException: ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known'))

Comment: Could you please try to install latest blob storage sdk as per this [link](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-blob/)?